# Is '>' sometimes used as a synonym for 'touch'?

Tags: bash, shell

(I'm not sure if I'm even asking this question in a way that's useful, nor whether or not the answer exists somewhere. Feel free to comment either way. The most useful reference I found is [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html).)

I've encountered some crufty shell scripts which consistently make use of the following construct:

`> ~/foo`

When executed, the line behaves the same way as touch (as far as my experiments were able to discover -- the excess code in the test script is meant to capture the surrounding code from the original):

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=this.$$
> ~/${FOO}
echo 'Foo'
```

produces:

```
$ ~/bin/test.sh
Foo
$ cat ~/this.15769
$ ls -l ~/this.15769
-rw-r--r-- 1 user    users 0 Mar  1 13:57 /home/user/this.15769
```

Is this the expected behavior? Are there side-effects I didn't consider/discover?

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps variable names are reserved for variables with meaning to the shell or other OS components; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace. Thus, it's good practice to use names with at least one lower-case character for your own variables, *especially* when you're putting them in the environment with `export`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` is absolutely not a synonym for `touch`. Using the `>` operator will truncate an existing file; `touch` will not.

```
$ echo hi > foo.txt
$ ls -l foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  3 Mar  1 14:21 foo.txt
$ touch foo.txt
$ ls -l foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  3 Mar  1 14:21 foo.txt
$ > foo.txt
$ ls -l foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  0 Mar  1 14:22 foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

One caveat: `>` will fail when its target is a directory, when `touch` will not.

---

```
>file
```

...creates a file if it doesn't exist, **truncates it to 0-byte if it does exist**, and updates its time. `touch` does not truncate its target's contents.